# How much data space is used by all scientific articles?

Tags: bigdata, research

I was wondering if there is any research or study made to calculate the volume of space is used by all scientific articles. It could be in pdf, txt, compressed, or any other format. Is there even a way to measure it?

Can some one point me towards realizing this study?

Regards and thanks.

Comment: Although this is about science, and data, I'm not sure the 'data science' StackExchange is the best place for this. Can you elaborate why this is of interest?

Comment: Try Fermi Estimation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem

Comment: As soon as you wrote a scientific article on this, you would be wrong.

Comment: Why would be an error? 

I thing that to resolve this problem I need data science tools. After know the total amount I want to extract patters of activity in each field for every year and study the dynamics of science and how this would be under the influence of historical events

Comment: I'm not confident about the feasibility of an attempt to solve this problem. You can certainly come up with a very rough estimate (and I see such numbers from time to time), but the accuracy is pretty low, considering the diversity of the outlets human knowledge can found at, as well as frequency of appearing of new research studies and even research repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking to quantify the amount of filespace used by a specific subset of data that we will label as "academic publications."

Well, to estimate, you could find stats on how many publications are housed at all the leading libraries (JSTOR, EBSCO, AcademicHost, etc) and then get the mean average size of each. Multiply that by the number of articles and whamo, you've got yourself an estimate.

Here's the problem, though: PDF files store the text from string `s` differently (in size) than, say, a text document stores that same string. Likewise, a compressed JPEG will store an amount of information `i` differently than a non-compressed JPEG. So you see we could have two of the same articles containing the same information `i` but taking up different amounts of memory `m`.

Are you looking to get a wordcount on the amount of scientific literature?

Are you looking to get an approximation of file system space used to store all academically published content in the world?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 

I'm looking for an estimation of the amount of scientific knowledge. After that I want to study the distribution between different fields. Maybe if I use a wordcount and I don't take care about the pictures the problem is more easy to resolve.